# How to dynamically assign ID to a checkbox in a for-each cycle

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, datatable

I have the following code in a ascx : I run a SQL query and I put it in a Datatable. Then I show the values in the page like this

```
<% For each row As DataRow In myDataTable.Rows %>

    <%=row("something") %>
    <%=row("somethingelse") %>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />

<% next %>
```

Now... how can I set the ID of the checkbox dynamically?
something like

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="<%=row("MyId")%>" runat="server" />
```

that obviously do not work.

I need to set the id as the value I get from the DB so if it is checked I can pass the checked id to another page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `row("MyId")` returns type of `object` so you need to convert it to `string` to be able to bind it to Checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="<%=row('MyId').ToString()%>" runat="server" />
```

See: [DataRow.Item[] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_Data_DataColumn_)

Comment: If I try to use runat server as shown, I get "Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs."

Comment: Could you try with `ID='<%=row("MyId").ToString()%>'` and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, would not a data control say like listview, or gridview be better here?

You can have this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" class="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName" HeaderStyle-Width="200"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ckActive" runat="server" 
                            Checked=<%# Eval("Active") %>   />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Now to load we have this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT TOP 10 FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Description, Active
             FROM tblHotels WHERE description is not null ORDER BY HotelName"

        GVHotels.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        GVHotels.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

and we get this:

[image]

So, it is a lot less work to do the above.

Even if you don't have a bound check box, you can even feed the grid the data, and display a un-bound check box for selecting rows if that what you need/want.